# Understanding Indexes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I am trying to understand indexes in MySQL. I know that an index created in a table can speed up executing queries and it can slow down the inserting and updating of rows.

When creating an index, I used this query on a table called `authors` that contains (`AuthorNum`, `AuthorFName`, `AuthorLName`, ...)

```
Create index Index_1 on Authors ([What to put here]);
```

I know I have to put a column name, but **which one?**

**Do I have to put the column name that will be compared in the Where statement when a user query the Table or what?**

Comment: Generally (but not always), in the majority of instances, indexes are determined by the `where`. How do users search for `Authors`? By firstname, last name, ... ?

Comment: I will assume they will search for the AuthorFName.

Comment: Indexes are not exclusively built from one column, some may be built from multiple columns and other may be built from just some of the info a column has. For example if you have a full `datetime` column but you know you're only going to filter records by `date` you can build an index based on the `datetime` column but only containing `date` info.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The Anatomy of an Index

An index is a distinct data structure within a database and is data redundancy. Its primary purpose is to provide an ordered representation of the indexed data through a logical ordering which is independent of the physical ordering.  We do this using a doubly linked list and a tree structure known as the balanced search tree (B-tree).  B-trees are nice because they keep data sorted and allow searches, access, insertions, and deletions in logarithmic time. Because of the doubly linked list, we are able to go backwards or forwards as needed on the index for various queries easily.  Inserts become simple since we only have to rearrange pointers to the different pieces of data.  Databases use these doubly linked list to connect leaf nodes (usually in a B+ tree or B-tree), each of which are stored in a page, and to establish logical ordering between the leaf nodes.  Operations like `UPDATE` or `INSERT` become slower because they are actually two writing operations in the filesystem (one for the table data and one for the index data).

### Defining an Optimal Index With WHERE

To define an optimal index you must not only understand how indexes work, but you must also understand how the application queries the data.  E.g., you must know the column combinations that appear in the `WHERE` clause.

A common restriction with queries on `LAST_NAME` and `FIRST_NAME` columns deals with case sensitivity.  For example, instead of doing an exact search like `Hotinger` we would prefer to match all results such as `HoTingEr` and so on.  This is very easy to do in a `WHERE` clause: we just say `WHERE UPPER(LAST_NAME) = UPPER('Hotinger')`

However, if we define an index of `LAST_NAME` and query, it will actually run a full table scan because the query is not on `LAST_NAME` but on `UPPER(LAST_NAME)`.  From the database's perspective, this is completely different.  So, in this case you should define the index on `UPPER(LAST_NAME)` instead.

Indexes do not necessarily have to be for one column.  For example, if the primary key is a composite key (consisting of multiple columns) it will create a *concatenated index* also known as a combined index.  Note that the ordering of the concatenated index has a **significant** impact on its usability and scalability so it must be chosen carefully. Basically, the ordering should match the way it is ordered in the `WHERE` clause.

### Defining an Optimal Index With LIKE

The position of the wildcard characters makes a huge difference.  `LIKE` clauses only use the characters **before** the wildcard during tree traversal; the rest do not narrow the scanned index range.  The more selective the prefix of the `LIKE` clause the more narrow the scanned index becomes.  This makes the index lookup faster.  As a tip, **avoid** `LIKE` clauses which lead with wildcards like `"%OTINGER%"`  For full-text searches, MySQL offers `MATCH` and `AGAINST` keywords.  Starting with MySQL 5.6, you can have full-text indexes. Look at [Full-Text Search Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html) from MySQL for more in-depth discussion on indexing these results.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, generally you need an index on the column or columns that you compare in the `WHERE` clause of your queries to speed up queries.

If you search by `AuthorFName`, then you create an index on that column. If they search by `AuthorLName`, then you create an index on that column.

In this case though, maybe what you should be looking at is a [FULLTEXT index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html). That would allow users to enter fuzzy queries, which would return a number of results ordered by relevance.

From the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html):

> Indexes are used to find rows with specific column values quickly.
>   Without an index, MySQL must begin with the first row and then read
>   through the entire table to find the relevant rows. The larger the
>   table, the more this costs. If the table has an index for the columns
>   in question, MySQL can quickly determine the position to seek to in
>   the middle of the data file without having to look at all the data. If
>   a table has 1,000 rows, this is at least 100 times faster than reading
>   sequentially. If you need to access most of the rows, it is faster to
>   read sequentially, because this minimizes disk seeks.

Answer (score 2):

### Limited length index:

When using `text` columns or very large `varchar` columns you won't be able to create an index over the entire length of the `text`/`varchar`, there are some limits (around 1024 ASCII characters in length).

In such a case you specify the length in the index declaration.

```
CREATE INDEX `my_limited_length_index` ON `my_table`(`long_text_content`(512));
-- please notice the use of the numeric length of the index after the column name
```

---

### Processed value index (apparently available in PostgreSQL not MySQL):

Indexes are not exclusively built from one column, some may be built from multiple columns and other may be built from just some of the info a column has. For example if you have a full `datetime` column but you know you're only going to filter records by `date` you can build an index based on the `datetime` column but only containing `date` info.

```
-- `my_table` has a `created` column of type timestamp
CREATE INDEX `my_date_created` ON `my_table`(DATE(`created`));
-- please notice the use of the DATE function which extracts only
-- the date from the `created` timestamp
```

Answer (score 2):

An index usually means a B-Tree. Understand the structure of the B-Tree and you'll understand what index can and cannot do.

In your particular case:

- `WHERE AuthorLName = 'something'` and `WHERE AuthorLName LIKE 'something%'` can be sped-up by an index on {AuthorLName}.
- `WHERE AuthorLName = 'something AND AuthorFName = 'something else'` can be sped-up by a composite index on {AuthorLName, AuthorFName} or {AuthorFName, AuthorLName}.
- `WHERE AuthorLName = 'something OR AuthorFName = 'something else'` (which doesn't make much sense, but is here as an example) can be sped-up by having two indexes: on {AuthorLName} *and* on {AuthorFName}.
- `WHERE AuthorLName LIKE '%something'` cannot be sped-up by a B-Tree index (cunsider full-text indexing).
- Etc...

See [Use The Index, Luke!](http://use-the-index-luke.com/) for a much more thorough treatment of the subject than possible in a simple SO post.

Answer (score 0):

index shall span the columns you are going to use in WHERE statement.

To better understand, here is an example:

```
SELECT * FROM Authors WHERE AuthorNum > 10 AND AuthorLName LIKE 'A%';
SELECT * FROM Authors WHERE AuthorLName LIKE 'Be%';
```

If you are often using the shown above queries, you are highly adviced to have two indexes:

```
Create index AuthNum_AuthLName_Index on Authors (AuthorNum, AuthorLName);
Create index AuthLName_Index on Authors (AuthorLName);
```

The key thing to remember: index shall have the same combiation of columns used in `WHERE` statements

Comment: OK, but how does MySQL finds the row using the index, does it keep a row number with it, or what?

Comment: This answer is partially incorrect, if I am reading it right.  The ordering of expressions in the where clause has nothing to do with the appropriate ordering of columns in indexes.  The expressions in the where clause can be evaluate  by the server in any logically valid order.

Comment: in my understanding indexed column will be a hash table stored in server's RAM. On query, it searches the stored RAM hash table with a hashed value from WHERE and gets the actual pointer to a row entry.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thank you, for pointing that out, I have modified the answer. Learning new things from answering questions is great.

Comment: @alandarev hashtables generate and store hashes for all records. When comparing equality the value being supplied in the `where` clause is hashed the same way (with the same hash function) and then it is compared against the hashes of the records in the table. This means that hashtable indexes can't be used for comparisons or likeness, only for strict equality. Which means that b-tree indexes will be used when comparisons are needed.

Comment: Also `FULLTEXT` indexing is yet another beast, it has its own underlying storage similar in concept to `b-trees` but it indexes words within the strings independently. In `PostgreSQL` the `FULLTEXT` indexing even has algorithmic options and special functions to help it compete with `Apache Solr` or `SphinxSearch` in terms of speed of the search and "weighted likeness" sorting of results.

Comment: Just a single composite index on {AuthorLName, AuthorNum} (in that order) should be sufficient for the queries above. Every additional index imposes a penalty on the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE performance and storage/caching.